# ReferenceError: angular is not defined index.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have looked at just about every answer to this question on SO but I can not find anything to fix the error in my case. I'm receiving it on startup of my application. I am using nodejs.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>ITSC</title>

<!-- scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/angular/angular.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header></header>
<div class="page" ng-controller="appController">
    <main class="cf">
      {{ message }}
</main>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var router = require('./public/js/routes')
var app = express();




app.use('/', router);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('app started');
});

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('appController',['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.message="Welcome to the app!!";

}]);
```

Comment: You're mixing server side javascript with client side. Your node.js code should be in it's own file and same with your angular app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, write your angular code in separate file, lets name if `app.js`.
Second you can't address angular like this `../node_modules/angular/angular.min.js`, its better to use tools like webpack or browserify to make a bundle. but for you test you can copy these file into your `public` folder. `/angular.min.js`

```
<!-- scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/angular.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app.js"></script>
```

`public/app.js`

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('appController',['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.message="Welcome to the app!!";

}]);
```